# Hashtable-like data structure with extra info to identify the preferred/current item

Tags: c#, data-structures, hashtable

Is there in C#, a Dictionary or Hashtable or similar structure, with attribute (like in XML) or extra piece of data to specify that one specific item in the Hashtable is the preferred/current one. I would like to do something like :

```
Hashtable myHashtable = new Hashtable(); 
myHashtable.Add(key1, item1);
myHashtable.Add(key2, item2, true); // true = specify this item2 as the preferred/current
myHashtable.Add(key3, item3);
```

Other than having this preferred/current information saved inside the items.

As for now, I am using my own structure as follows, but still did not check all corner cases :

```
public class HashtableWithCurrent : Hashtable
{
    String _currentKey = String.Empty;

    public void Add(object key, object value, bool current)
    {
        // TODO make sure key is a String

        //
        base.Add(key, value);

        //
        _currentKey = (String)key;
    }

    public override void Remove(object key)
    {
        base.Remove(key);

        // key also
        if (_currentKey == key)
            ClearCurrentKey();
    }

    public String CurrentKey
    {
        get
        {
            return _currentKey;
        }
    }

    public void ClearCurrentKey()
    {
        _currentKey = String.Empty; // via a function rather than a setter to avoid unwanted setting
    }
}
```

Comment: Write your own that inherits from `Dictionary<tkey,tval>` and has a property `Current`.

Comment: When you create your own, be sure to take into account the possibility that the `Current` item could be removed from the dictionary. If the current item is deleted, do you set `Current` to `null`? Or do you check that `Current` still exists in the dictionary whenever `Current.get` is called? Handling all the cases can be a bit tricky.

Comment: Indeed it may become tricky, this is why I asked if there is something builtin in the framework. I am posting the code in the updated question.

Comment: Don't use `HashTable`.  Use a `Dictionary`.  You're only creating a world of hurt for yourself otherwise.

Comment: You'll also need to override the `Clear` method, so it clears the current key. And related to Servy's comment: is there a particular reason you're working with `HashTable` rather than `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>`? The latter is typically the better solution.

Comment: Thanks for the Clear method. And switched to Dictionary

Answer (score 0):

You can write your own, but I think you don't need it. Just use one private field in a class where you use a `Hashtable`:

```
class MyClass
{
    private object _currentKey;
    private Hashtable _myHashtable = new Hashtable(); 
    public void Method()
    {
        // ...
        _myHashtable.Add(key1, item1);
        _myHashtable.Add(key2, item2);
        _currentKey = key2;
        _myHashtable.Add(key3, item3);
    } 
}
```

Comment: I preferred to write my own, in order to keep currentKey associated with the hashtable.

Comment: You mean that you need to encapsulate this invariant in a separate class. It is right way of thinking, but in this particular case overhead costs of this action are the way bigger than benefits.